# ¿Como evitar que alerte la salida de la página si el formulario se guarda?

Tags: javascript, alert

Buen dia

quiero evitar que la alerta de que está saliendo la página aparezca cuando el formulario se guarda ya que siempre que se va a salir de la página o se refresca aparece y está bien pero no cuando guardo el formulario  creería que hay que realizar una condición pero no he dado como hacerla

**js**

```
            window.onbeforeunload = preguntarAntesDeSalir;
        
        function preguntarAntesDeSalir(){
        return "¿Seguro que quieres salir?";
        }
```

**html**

```
<p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <input id="send" form="registro" type="submit" value= "Finalizar" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-lg "  width="50%" height="30px"> 
      </p>
```

en concreto que cuando se presione este botón no se ejecute la alerta de que está saliendo de la página por que se esta guardando

Answer (score 0):

ya lo logré solucionar por si algún novato igual que yo le surge la misma duda

**js**
condicion

```
            function asegurar_cierre(valor){
            if(valor==1){
                window.onbeforeunload = function (){

                    return '!!Estas seguro de salir sin guardar se perderan los cambios realizados!!';
                }
            }else if (valor==2){
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            }
        }
```

**html**

```
            <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <input id="send" form="registro" type="submit" onclick="asegurar_cierre(2)" value= "Finalizar" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-lg "  width="50%" height="30px"> 
        </p>
```

básicamente recoge el valor de onclick que es dos y desactiva la alerta también se puede hacer con onchange etc. según el valor entra en la condición y activa o desactiva la alerta es una solucion simple sin valida formulario